# Serialize JSON Subclasses Information in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization

I need some help with one **JSON** serialization Problem.

I have one class like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorFormula("type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value =TextFileCardEntity.class, name = "textCard"),
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MultipleChoiceFileCard.class, name = "choiceCard")@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MultipleChoiceFileCard.class, name = "choiceCard")})
public class FileCardEntity extends ResourceEntity implements Cloneable {
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private FileCardType type;
    private Date expirationDate;
        .....
```

I also have two classes that extends of FileCardEntity:

```
@JsonTypeName(value = "textCard")
public class TextFileCardEntity extends FileCardEntity {
    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    private String question;

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    private String answer;
        .......
```

AND

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
@JsonTypeName(value = "choiceCard")
public class MultipleChoiceFileCard extends FileCardEntity {
    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    private String question;

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    private String crib;
        ......
```

I use the next Code in order to deserialize the information:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
final ObjectWriter typedWriter = mapper.writerWithType(mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, classElement));
System.out.println(typedWriter.writeValueAsString(elements));
```

Where elements is: `List<?> elements`

When I deserialize information from Server about TextFileCardEntity, I get:

```
[{"textCard":{"status":"ACTIVE","lastModified":1366293513200,"expirationDate":0.....
```

That is ok

When I attempt serialize information about TextFileCardEntity for example to Server, the code sends:

```
[{"FileCardEntity":{"status":"ACTIVE","lastModified":1366378327069,"shared":false,"orderID":0........
```

That is not ok because I need the syntax to be similar has in the deserialization information 
--> `[{"textCard":{"status"....` and not `[{"FileCardEntity":{"status"....`

What can I do?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question; are you saying that the server gives you the proper output in JSON but your client is sending the wrong JSON back to the server?